# Adding Setters to a function template

Tags: c++

I am trying to add setter to my project as a requirement but am stuck on making it work. I commented out the areas I have to add it but everything I have looked up has not worked. I know I am close but everything seems to not work.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Holder
{
private:
    T thing;
    int number;    //add an integer data member that stores the number of data members of whatever class is stored in "thing"

public:
    void standardInput();
    void standardOutput();
    void setNumber(int);  // declare a setter function for the new data member

};
template <class T>
void Holder<T>::standardInput()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "You will be asked to enter " << n.setNumber << " items" << endl; // a line of output that use the data member with the number
    cin >> Holder<T>::thing;
}
template <class T>
void Holder<T>::standardOutput()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Here's the data you requested: " << endl;
    cout << Holder<T>::thing << endl;
}

template<class T>
void Holder<T>::setNumber(int n)   //implement the setter function for the new data member
{
    setNumber = n;
}


// This is the first of two custom classes
class Student
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Student&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Student&);
private:
    string name;
    double tuiton;

};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Student& a)
{
    out << "The Student " << a.name << " Tuiton is: " << a.tuiton << endl;
    return out;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Student& a)
{
    cout << "Enter the name of student: ";
    in >> a.name;
    cout << "What is the Price of tuiton? ";
    in >> a.tuiton;
    return in;
}

// This is the second of two custom classes
class FastFood
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, FastFood&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, FastFood&);
private:
    int valueNumber;
    double cost;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, FastFood& a)
{
    out << " The Combo Number is  " << a.valueNumber << " .It costs " << a.cost << endl;
    return out;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in, FastFood& a)
{
    cout << "What is the Combo number? ";
    in >> a.valueNumber;
    cout << "Enter cost: ";
    in >> a.cost;
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "For an integer: " << endl;
    Holder<int> val;
                                            // use the setter to store 1.
    val.standardInput();
    val.standardOutput();

    cout << "For a Student:" << endl;


    Holder<Student> aCollegeStudent;
                                            // use the setter to store 2.
    aCollegeStudent.standardInput();
    aCollegeStudent.standardOutput();


    Holder<FastFood> vMeal;
                                           // use the setter to store 3.
    vMeal.standardInput();
    vMeal.standardOutput();



    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is supposed to ask the integer along with the student and fastfood information. I required to add a setter in the template but wont need to use a getter due to standard input and output just cant figure out the right way to do it.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `"everything seems to not work"`.  As an aside note that in `Holder<T>::setNumber` you have `setNumber = n;` -- `Holder<T>` doesn't have any data member named `setNumber` but it does have one named `number`.

Comment: Thats what I am not sure about when I said everything seems to not work. What I meant was everything I tried to do with setting up a setter has not worked. I had post what my code currently looks like I have changed the setter multiple times and commented out where I am required to put it for this assignment.

Comment: But you need to describe the symptoms.  Does it compile?  If not then please edit your question to include the compilation error messages.

Comment: It compiles just fine I just do not know how to add a setter to a function template and was searching all over for some type of example of it or any advice on how to go about it.

Comment: The line "cout << "You will be asked to enter " << n.setNumber << " items" << endl; "  contains an error: "error: ‘n’ was not declared in this scope" ... do you see why?

Comment: Do you understand that IF n was in scope, it is an integer, and would not have any methods?  I think you need only decide _how_ to get the _value_ of 'n' to your setter method (you are fairly close, don't give up).

Comment: "It compiles just fine " -- perhaps the code you presented to us is not what you  are 'compiling just fine' ?

Comment: I got it figured out thanks again for the help. I am still learning so I figured this would be a great place to turn when stuck or needing advice. Im only week three in my C++ class so its still taking time to get used too.